# Is there BAT file can run in TABLET?

Tags: tablet

How can I run a bat file in tablet? If cannot, have any file extension can instead bat file to run in tablet?

I want to run a website through **bat** file in tablet.

because we don't want the user using tablet to run other application.

> It allows a web pop-up window.